# Ray picking with gluUnProject() into world coordinates

Tags: math, 3d, matrix

I set up a scene using:

```
glViewport(0,0,screen->w,screen->h);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
const float wh = (float)screen->w/(float)screen->h;
gluPerspective(zoom,wh,1,10);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0,0,-3); // puts model inside z-range
```

Later, when the user clicks, I want to calculate a ray in world coordinates for my intersection test (***not*** using `glReadPixels()` to get the z):

```
double mv[16], p[16], a, b, c, d, e, f;
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,mv);
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX,p);
matrix_t _mv, _p;
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,_mv.f);
glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX,_p.f);
const matrix_t inv = (_p*_mv).inverse();
GLint viewport[4];
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT,viewport);
gluUnProject(x,viewport[3]-y,0,mv,p,viewport,&a,&b,&c);
const vec_t origin(vec_t(a,b,c)*inv);
gluUnProject(x,viewport[3]-y,1,mv,p,viewport,&d,&e,&f);
const vec_t dest(vec_t(d,e,f)*inv);
ray_t ray(origin,dest-origin);
```

Unfortunately I misunderstand how to convert the ray from camera coordinates to world coordinates - my ray misses.

How do you correctly convert the ray to world coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find my answer to a similar question useful.

[Click to zoom in WebGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613718/click-to-zoom-in-webgl/5616743#5616743)

That answer pertains to WebGL and Javascript.  I don't work in C++ and OpenGL. but looking at your code I would think that gluUnproject is already using the inverses of the `p` and `mv` matrices.  You multiplication of the result by `inv` is therefore redundant, and is probably what is screwing up your result.