# zooming out in webgl

Tags: zooming, webgl

I saw here [Click to zoom in WebGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613718/click-to-zoom-in-webgl) how to zoom in to a particular point. How can I reverse that functionality- i.e. zoom out?

Answer (score 1):

Change the statement

```
  vec3.subtract(eye,dir) ;
```

to

```
  vec3.add(eye,dir) ;
```

This moves the eye in the opposite direction from before.

Here's the modified live example: http://jsfiddle.net/3wwdU/1/

Comment: Thanks brainjam. That was really helpful. Since you seem quite knowledgeable on the subject, can you point me in the direction of a page which explains how to identify a 3d point from screen coordinates (user input)?

Comment: @yelan,You might find this answer useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613718/click-to-zoom-in-webgl/5616743#5616743